# Correctly converting a NumPy array to a PyTorch tensor running on the gpu

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have created a `DataLoader` that looks like this

```
class ToTensor(object):
    def __call__(self, sample):
        return torch.from_numpy(sample).to(device)

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, transform=None):
        self.data = data
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample = self.data[idx, :]

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample
```

I am using this data loader like so

```
dataset = MLBDataset(
        data=data,
        transform=transforms.Compose([
            ToTensor()
        ]))
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
dataiter = iter(dataloader)
x = dataiter.next()
```

This fails with the message

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=55 error=3 : initialization error
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=55 error=3 : initialization error
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=55 error=3 : initialization error
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=55 error=3 : initialization error
...
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (3) : initialization error at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1549628766161/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:55
```

For the `return` command inside `ToTensor()`, in fact any attempt to move the tensor te the GPU will fail inside that class. I have tried:

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [25, 26, 27, 28]],
             [[11, 12, np.nan, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18], [35, 36, 37, 38]]])
print(torch.from_numpy(a).to(device))
```

inside the body of `__call__` in `ToTensor()` and it fails with the same message, whereas it succeeds everywhere else.

Why is this error generated and how can I resolve this?

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1666. Look at apaszke answer.

Comment: First check if CUDA works:
`import torch`
`x = torch.randn(2, 2, device='cuda:0')`
`print(x)`

Comment: @TarasSavchyn I think CUDA works without issue, at least for any other tests that I have performed.

Comment: I see.. Maybe try this one: `X = torch.from_numpy(X).cuda("cuda:0")`

Comment: @TarasSavchyn I completely re-wrote the question hopefully making it a lot clearer, it was not an issue of not having the correct `device` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.cuda.set_device(0)

X = np.ones((1, 10), dtype=np.float32)
print(type(X), X)
X = torch.from_numpy(X).cuda(0)
print(type(X), X)

model = nn.Linear(10, 10).cuda(0)
Y = model(X)
print(type(Y), Y)
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
<class 'torch.Tensor'> tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], device='cuda:0')
<class 'torch.Tensor'> tensor([[ 0.4867, -1.0050,  0.4872, -0.0260, -0.0788,  0.0161,  1.2210, -0.3957,
          0.2097,  0.2296]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1494) this might be related to multiprocessing issues. You can find the following [workaround](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1494#issuecomment-305993854).